# SharePoint Online vs. SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, office365

What are the *feature* differences between Office 365's SharePoint Online vs. SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Download the "Microsoft SharePoint Online for Enterprises Service Description" document:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13602

Direct Link:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/9/6/096C9441-8089-4655-ABB3-DC0ABA01A98D/Microsoft%20SharePoint%20Online%20for%20Enterprises%20Service%20Description.docx

Staring at page 30 Appendix B: SharePoint Online and SharePoint Server Feature Comparison

More:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2010/11/03/office-365-part-4-sharepoint-online.aspx

For more sharepoint Q&A check out: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. Infrastructure : SharePoint Online is part of software as a service (SaaS) by Microsoft meaning this software is fully managed by Microsoft however for SP 2010 our IT team has to manage it. Microsoft will take care about this software but in SP 2010 we are responsible to manage software as well and even its hosting environment etc.
2. App Model - SP 2010 has sandbox and farm level solutions but from SP 2013 on-wards Microsoft introduced app model which is also called as add-in model.
3. Third party integration - third party software needs be installed on machines in case of SP 2010 but in SPOL - since it is cloud platform third party integration will come as APP/Add-in.
4. Mobile compatibility - SPOL has new view experience named as 'Modern View' which is compatible to the mobile devices. This feature is not available in SP 2010
5. Microsoft supports - SP 2010 support from Microsoft will end by coming DEC 2020.
6. Cost - SPOL has low cost however SP 2010 is bit costly in terms of hosting infra, licenses and additional IT team cost to manage it.
7. Search - SPOL has great search feature including FAST search, display templates etc. by default but in case of SP 2010 we need to take care of additionally.
8. Office 365 integration - SPOL can easily be integrate with other office 365 tools like Power BI, Microsoft Flow, Power Apps, One drive but difficult to integrate with SP 2010 environment.
9. External Sharing - Sharing site with other Microsoft accounts is seamlessly possible using SPOL but it quite tough in case of SP 2010.

Can not capture all the details over the forum.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online is similar to SharePoint 2010 only difference you will find in features supported.
and in architecture wise client side proxies are more supported in online.

In SharePoint online we can not deploy farm solutions directly. We need to create everything as sandbox solution and then we can achieve the results.

Web-parts and (Designer) Declarative workflows are allowed inside SharePoint online. For custom workflows you need to create SP 2010 designer reusable workflow and import those inside visual studio and publish as sandbox solution. This way we can install workflows as sandbox solution in SharePoint online.

you can fine more difference on MSDN sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sharepoint 2010 you have to setup your own server and you have to do all the configurations. If you use sharepoint online you have to buy licence depends on how many users you have. There may be problems on server side which you can only watch. But if you use sharepoint 2010 you can interfere it.

Answer (score 0):

From a development / extensibility view SP Online allows you to use SPFX (SharePoint Framework) to add new functionality to simplify interacting with external Api'S

Answer (score -1):

You have lots of differences in features and functionalities offered by both, the key decision for you is how much you want to pay for that piece of work and what is the main features that you are expecting with less customization.

SharePoint 2010 might be cheaper, but more effort needed to implement stuff and lot of features might be deprecated or not existing to use because you have now 2013 and 2016 as well SharePoint Online [on cloud] with more new easy features to use. On the other hand SharePoint Online is the future, you will pay per user licence which might be a bit expensive, but it worth the price because it 's fully supported with lots of new features available to use and more yet to come, such as: Delve, Office Groups and other cool stuff with Office 365 which is ready for you to use.

SharePoint 2010
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd776256%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

SharePoint Online
https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-collaboration-software